# Do the Java or JIT compilers optimise Arrays.asList when the parameters are unchanged?

Tags: java, jit

Eg: `Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3")`

Would this create a new array (for varargs) and a new ArrayList every time it is called during the lifetime of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned list is mutable. This must return a different List with each call.

Comment: So obvious. But if I were to use Lists.of, which does return an immutable list, would that be optimised at some point?

Comment: @Sorin - It is allowed to be, according to the [documentation for unmodifiable lists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable): *Factories are free to create new instances or reuse existing ones. Therefore, identity-sensitive operations on these instances (reference equality (==), identity hash code, and synchronization) are unreliable and should be avoided.*

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, for methods with `Varargs` java will create a temporary array and send it to method. so with this method implementation:

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}
```

which create new `ArrayList` and constructor of `ArrayList`:

```
private final E[] a;

ArrayList(E[] array) {
    a = Objects.requireNonNull(array);
}
```

so new ArrayList contain reference to objects of list or `Varargs` sent to method.
I think there is no difference between a array and `Varargs`. for `Varargs` compiler will create a temporary array and in run-time there is no difference alot.
However always between JVM there is difference which you must read about it but I don't think there is a difference between `Varargs` and normal array.